# Sorting content list alphabetically

Tags: nodes

Is there any way to sort Drupal's content list in the admin area alphabetically by title? I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to override the default content list or to create an alternative one using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

With views it's easy to create sortable tables. I believe a view of the content listing is already predefined in either VBO or Views.